# How to connect to a remote device using A2DP on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, a2dp

I want to connect to a Bluetooth device and have my app send to it audio over A2DP.
So my question is:

- How to scan for a bluetooth device?
- How to pair with it ?
- How to send audio to the paired device?

I am familiar with `Corebluetooth` but its not compatible for Bluetooth that is not low energy, so what framework should i use?
Should the user connect the device throw the settings of the app or can my deal with that?

I know there is a lot of questions but all the information that i found was for android.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi let me answer your questions one by one

first of all you dont use **CoreBluetooth**

you will use **[AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/)** and/or  **[CoreAudio](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html)**  (which is a really huge framework with AudioUnits and AudioQueue and much more)

BUT if you just want to play Audio you may not need to dive into CoreAudio
[AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/) is built on CoreAudio and can easily play and record from Bluetooth devices

```
How to send audio to the paired device?
```

Core Audio and AVFoundations both have mechanism for getting and sending audio to Bluetooth Audio devices from/to your iphone

```
How to scan for a bluetooth device and How to pair with it ?
```

this is done via Bluetooth Settings in your iphone.you just trun yout BT Speaker ON and search then you Pair it for future use

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I am used to using 'Corebluetooth' where there i scan and receive an array of peripherals in the area and connect if nedded, in this case how do tell core audio to send audio to a specific connected bluetooth device ?